# Auto-Delete AWS resources that use TLS1.1 or older

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, security, automation, tls1.2

I am a newbie and really need some help for a script please.

How would I automate the deletion of any public facing endpoint resources(API gateway, ELB, Cloudfront distribution, ELBv2) in my AWS Environment that are using a TLS version of 1.1 or below?

I am trying to make only the ones with TLS 1.2 remain.

I have resources that have a weak TLS version and am trying to automate the deletion process.

Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Iterate through all relevant regions, list all resources of the relevant services, check the specific property, call the endpoint to delete the resource. There is no way other than coding it.

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you. Do you know what a code template would look like? that is was i am trying to do. I am trying to automate it. But have very little experience and need some help on the code.